# Regain a Connection to Hashem

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

At times, one’s connection to Hashem could fade. According to various sources, what is the fastest way one can regain a connection to Hashem?

Comment: When have you felt most connected to HaShem? Tefila, learning, gemilut chassadim, music, food, dancing?

Comment: related: [How to maintain devotion to Hashem in a low period in one's life?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69762/11501)

Comment: What do you mean by 'connection'?

Comment: One very good way to gain connection to Hashem is to learn about Him. The Torah is Hashem speaking to you personally, and revealing His desires and wisdom to you. Chabad Chassidus specializes in Yediyat Hashem as well, so Tanya etc.