# Spiritual Boredom

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, commentaries, synagogue, kavana-concentration

Because of all the routines, standard prayers,  repeating cycles etc, someone told me that going to the synagogue became quite boring for him. He still saw the value of those things, but he didn’t find it right to do those things if his soul wasn’t into it, if his mind and heart weren’t into it.

Because of this I began to wonder what the Rabbis/Commentators teach about such ‘boredom’.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69762/11501

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/190/759

Answer (score 2):

My teacher said it is imperative to periodically learn a new commentary on the Siddur in order to find new meaning in the old words.

May I recommend [this](https://www.judaicaplace.com/the-koren-siddur-ani-tefilla-compact-ashkenaz-paperback/9789653016941/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlLbY6q_64AIVg8DICh3mPAWfEAQYAiABEgIjEvD_BwE)? It helped me personally. And there are dozens of more options.

Comment: While this is a good temporary fix, does it really address the core issue. If you had the same problem with your wife, would you tell her to wear different clothing? Sure it might help in the moment but there’s a bigger issue at hand.

Comment: Because the words of Tefillah ARE infinitely complex and ever-renewing. A person needs to invest effort in order to tap into their holiness and power.

Comment: Rav Elya Lopian, I believe, was wont to tell his students to change their seat or change their siddur. Even a small change can bring freshness to rote habits.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/190/759

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that we spend so much time focusing on learning. We overly focus on intellectual stimulation. Even [LN6595's teacher's advice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100826/1570) will only help for a short while, until you find the next seifer... And what do you do when you're between siddurim and a new one didn't come out yet?

See my answer to [Experience-based advice for focusing and slowing down prayers?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100826/1570) for a two-pronged approach to prayer.

My shorter but no less critical advice is to engage in hisbodedus, the way Breslovers do. It can get you used to speaking to the Almighty as an experience.

My longer advice, which got into some detail, was all about the Kelm version of Mussar's practice of hispa'alus -- encountering texts in a way that they have experiential and emotional impact. The word "hispa'alus" means to work on yourself.

Comment: You may have something to contribute to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/190/759

Comment: I replaced the answer here with a teaser, and moved the actual thesis there.